# Getting 'Undefined' property error, when inheriting using closure tools

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I am trying to implement a custom component using closure tools.
but it always give error about 'goog.ui' being undefined. Here are my files:

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
goog.require('goog.ui.Component');

var dummyComponent = function() {
};
goog.inherits(dummyComponent, goog.ui.Component);
```

This is just a stub code, I know the call to goog.base is missing, but I am more concerned with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
```

I already have `goog.require()` in place, what else should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around I found something that worked for me, I had to do goog.require(...)` inside html file once.

Updated HTML file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script>
         goog.require('goog.ui.Component');
    </script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't set the result of `goog.require('goog.ui.Component')` to a variable:

```
var goog = goog.require('goog.ui.Component');

var dummyComponent = function() {
};
goog.inherits(dummyComponent, goog);
```

Comment: `goog.require()` returns null